# Jackson ObjectCodec to string json

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

With Jackson how can I safely cast a JsonNode to a JSON string.

```
public class WrappedMessage extends JsonDeserializer<WrappedMessage> {
    @Override
    public WrappedMessage deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();

        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
        JsonNode payload = node.get("payload");
        // How to get the payload as JSON

        return new WrappedMessage();
    }
}
```

It is possible to do this with `ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString` and I know in normal context the `ObjectCode` can be cast to `ObjectMapper`, but doesn't seem to be very clean.

Also it possible to do `payload.toString()`, but the documentation states:

> Method that will produce developer-readable representation of the
>   node; which may **or may not** be as valid JSON. If you want valid
>   JSON output (or output formatted using one of other Jackson supported
>   data formats) make sure to use {@link ObjectMapper} or {@link
>   ObjectWriter} to serialize an instance, for example: String json =
>   objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode);

So this isn't safe to use either.

The last possibility what I see is to construct a new `ObjectMapper`, but doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to create a `JsonGenerator` and use `ObjectCodec.writeTree`:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator jgen = codec.getFactory().createGenerator(writer);    
codec.writeTree(jgen, payload);
String jsonPayload = writer.toString();
```